# C++ struct to Java class

Tags: java, c++, struct

I want to convert a c++ struct like this:

```
typedef struct FEATUREINFO
{
    string str_ID;
    char* c_ID;
    double* featureData;
    int group;
    bool bPrint;
    IplImage *t_faceImg;
}FEATUREINFO;
```

And I will use it :

```
FEATUREINFO * p_featureNode = new FEATUREINFO[100];
for(int j=0; j<100 ; j++)
{
    p_featureNode[j].featureData = (double*)calloc(t_featureLen,sizeof(double));
    p_featureNode[j].bPrint = false;
}
```

In Java code I wrote my code :

```
class FEATUREINFO
{
    string str_ID;
    char[] c_ID;
    public Double[] featureData;
    int group;
    public boolean bPrint;
    //IplImage *t_faceImg;
    public FEATUREINFO()
    {
        this.featureData = new Double[1280] ;
    }     
} // class FEATUREINFO
```

And worte a simple code to test whether I success:

```
FEATUREINFO[] p_featureNode = new FEATUREINFO[100];
p_featureNode[5].featureData[2] = 100.5 ;  // this line will error!!! =(
Log.d(Tag_Test, "featureData :" + p_featureNode[5].featureData[2] ) ;
```

I'm a beginner of Java, please help me! Thank you very much!

There is my error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/swow5.png

Thank you again!!!!! =D

Comment: Why are you using `typedef` in C++? Just using the structure name is enough. Also, why don't you have a constructor in the C++ structure? Why don't you use `new` to allocate in C++?

Comment: Please use `class FeatureInfo`, `String strID;`, `char[] cID;`and `double[] featureData;` in Java, and mark everything `private`.

Comment: This C/C++ is already done by other. He told me to convert to Android. =(

Comment: Also, when posting questions about errors, please include the actual (complete and unmodified) errors *in the question*.

Comment: OK! I will post my error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ initializes each array element to a default state (calling the default constructor for each array element) - Java does not.

You need something like:

```
FEATUREINFO[] p_featureNode = initializeWithDefaultFEATUREINFOInstances(100);
...

public static FEATUREINFO[] initializeWithDefaultFEATUREINFOInstances(int length)
{
    FEATUREINFO[] array = new FEATUREINFO[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new FEATUREINFO();
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!
But I wondering, if I want to create 1280 featureData, how to do?

Comment: Isn't this done in your constructor? Once the statement "array[i] = new FEATUREINFO();" executes, the single statement in your constructor is called which initializes 'featureData'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class FEATUREINFO(){

    string str_ID;
    char c_ID;
    double featureData;
    int group;
    bool bPrint;
    IplImage t_faceImg;

  public /*noreturntypeforconstructor*/ FEATUREINFO(String a, char b, double c, int d, bool e, IplImage f){

    this.str_ID = a; // the inputs to the constructor
    this.c_ID = b;
    this.featureData = c;
    this.group = d;
    this.bPrint = e;
    this.t_faceImg = f;

  } // if all values arenot know before object is create sostandard constructor isused (FEATUREINFO(/*no args*/))

  public String getstrID(){

    return this.str_ID;

  }

  public String setstrID(String inputString){

    this.str_ID = inputString;

  } // getter and setters for each member....

} // i understand that you probably already know all of this but it was fun writing it :)
```

Comment: Before you post an answer, please at least learn how to format your code.  Also, the OP asked for Java, not C

Comment: cheers for input this is the first question ive fully answered! well up for SO now :D haha

Comment: and to the the inquisitor, this may seem like overkill compared to C, however it essentially allows you to construct your own 'struct' with your own rules, and your own methods, love java its well good :)